# Under what condition does a homotopy of paths induce a path homotopy?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Let $H: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a continuous function to a topological space $X$.

Consider the following continuous paths in $X$

$\alpha(t):= H(0,t) : [0,1] \rightarrow X$

$\beta(t):=H(1,t):[0,1] \rightarrow X$

$\gamma(t):=H(t,0):[0,1] \rightarrow X$

$\delta(t):= (H(t,1))^{-1}:[0,1] \rightarrow X$

[image]

**My questions are the following:**

1. Under what condition on $H$, there exists a path homotopy $H_p: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $\alpha$ to $\delta*\beta*\gamma$ where $*$ is the concatenation of paths?
2. If we ask the same question in the category of smooth manifolds(after assuming technical conditions like paths with sitting instances..etc, so that the concatenation of smooth paths is smooth..etc), will the same answer(as for topological spaces) work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A path homotopy will always exists because $I \times I$ is contractible so you can find a path homotopy between one of the sides of the square and the concatenation of the other three sides, you can then compose this homotopy with $\alpha$, $\beta$, etc. to get the path homotopy you need. Could you give more context as to this problem? Why are you trying to find this path homotopy?

Comment: @feynhat I have not assumed that $X$ is path connected. Is it still true? Also, in smooth set up, what will be the situation?  Regarding the context: I need to understand this path homotopy for a very technical situation. Describing the technical situation will take a very long way from the question itself. I hope I could express my situation.

Comment: Path connectedness of X is irrelevant, because the image of H will lie completely in one of the path component. This means that each of $\alpha$, $\beta$, etc. all will lie in one of the path components.

Comment: @feynhat Ok. Will the same argument hold in the smooth set up?

Comment: What exactly do you want to show in the smooth setting? Are you asking whether there is a smooth path homotopy? I am not sure how to pose this problem in the smooth setting because $I \times I$ is not a manifold (its not even manifold with boundary), it is a manifold 'with corners'. I am not sure how one define smoothness of map in that case. I would guess that the idea is to think of $I \times I$ as a subset $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we say that $H: I \times I \to X$ is smooth if $H$ can be smoothly extended to an open neighborhood of $I \times I$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If we work with this definition, then I think the same argument will hold in the smooth setting, you just need to check smoothness at each step.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @feynhat. The continuity of $H$ is sufficient to get a homotopy map. For example consider the following diagram.[image: Topology] There is no impact of connectedness of $X$. For your second question: it will work on manifolds also as they are topological spaces too. The key factor is the continuity of $H$.